# How do I dynamically insert a CSS class using PHP?

Tags: php, css

What's wrong with the following code? I would like to dynamically insert "current" CSS class when the respective `<li>` element is clicked. Thanks!

```
<?php 
$pg = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
?>

<section>
    <aside>       
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="<?php if($pg == 'index.php?page=about.php'){echo 'current';} ?>"><a href="index.php?page=about.php">About</a></li>                       
            <li class=""><a href="">Services</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
<section>
```

Comment: That's an HTML class. There is no such thing as a CSS class. The term sometimes gets used to mean "rule-set", "class selector", "any selector" and "property". This is confusing, so please don't use the term.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add to the element a class when the user clicks on it, i.e. on the client side?

Comment: The syntax looks fine, I would echo out $pg onto the page, it's possible that it is not exactly what you are expecting, that way you can what your condition needs to be.

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` returns the full working dir (everything after /public_html/)

Comment: you can try this, Add if statement and assign value to few variables/ or one variable. then inside html code, add php variable into class section,  Ex- <div class="<?php $myvar; ?> other-class" >

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with:

```
<?php 
$pg = $_GET['page'];

$allow = array('about.php', 'main.php', 'other.php');
if ( !in_array($pg, $allow) ) {
    $pg = 'default_value';
}
?>

<section>
    <aside>       
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="<?php if($pg == 'about.php'){echo 'current';} ?>"><a href="index.php?page=about.php">About</a></li>                       
            <li class=""><a href="">Services</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
<section>
```

Comment: +1 But you could also explain him the security flaws his method possibly has.

Comment: You could use the most recent syntax for arrays instead of `$maybe = array(...)` you can use `$yes = [...]`

Answer (score 2):

```
<li class="<?php echo ($_GET['page'] == 'about.php')? 'current' : 'normal'; ?>">
  <a href="index.php?page=about.php">About</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` doesn't return the $_GET vars (`?page=about.php`)

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will start with `/` and will not include the query string.

You should probably check `$_GET['page']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your looking for clicked at runtime you need javascript not php. Something like this using jQuery will work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav >ul li').click(function(){
        //remove all current classes
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
});
```