# How do you use php variables in css properly?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have some variables in php which i want to use in my css, how would I go in using these in CSS ?

```
-webkit-clip-path: inset(0 1500px ("<?php echo $y; ?>") 0);
-moz-clip-path: inset(0 1500px ("<?php echo $y; ?>") 0);
-o-clip-path: inset(0 1500px ("<?php echo $y; ?>") 0);
clip-path: inset(0 1500px ("<?php echo $y; ?>") 0);
```

This doesnt seem to work, with or without the quotes around the .

Comment: use inline style with same css property to html, it will work.

Comment: Apparently I just removed the quotes and it works now

Answer (score 1):

You can't render PHP inside of a .css file.  You should use inline styles in your HTML that's generated by a PHP file.

That is the direct answer to your question.  The indirect answer:

Use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).  They're designed for doing exactly what you want here: using variables in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do use it like this, inline in the HTML:

```
 <style>
-webkit-clip-path: inset(0 1500px ("<?php echo $y; ?>") 0);
-moz-clip-path: inset(0 1500px ("<?php echo $y; ?>") 0);
-o-clip-path: inset(0 1500px ("<?php echo $y; ?>") 0);
clip-path: inset(0 1500px ("<?php echo $y; ?>") 0);
</style>
```

Comment: Opps, i forgot to mention that i have already included the style tags around it, however the values within my php variable $y (containing something like 500px string) doesnt seem to work in the css

Comment: @Nightflare11 You need to provide more data then. It's a `PHP` file or an `HTML5`? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your style.css to style.php and linking it with your html file like this

`<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.php' />`

At the top of your new style.php file set the Content-type back to CSS:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?>
```

Now you are good to go... Set up and use your variables

Answer (score 0):

You can :
1) Insert the value in the inline CSS directly (refer [How do I dynamically insert a CSS class using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187804/how-do-i-dynamically-insert-a-css-class-using-php))
2) Insert the value from PHP into CSS via jQuery (refer [Add CSS class based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158211/add-css-class-based-on-id))

P.S. : Search for existing question-answers before you post